# How to show the following morphism is independent of the choice of neighborhoods?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Görtz and Wedhorn's AGI (3.4)

> Let $X$ be a scheme. Let $x ∈ X$, and let $U \subset X$ be an affine open neighborhood of $x$, say $U = \mathop{Spec} A$. Denote by $p \subset A$ the prime ideal of $A$ corresponding to $x$. Then $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} = \mathcal{O}_{U,x} = A_p$, and the natural homomorphism $A \to A_p$ gives us a morphism 
>   $$j_x \colon \mathop{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,x} = \mathop{Spec} A_p  \to \mathop{Spec}A = U \subset X $$
>   of schemes. By Proposition 3.2 (2) this morphism is independent of the choice of $U$.

The Proposition 3.2 (2) is the following:

> Let $X$ be a scheme. The affine open subscheme are a basis of the topology.

**My question:** 
Why  is this morphism  independent of the choice of $U$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the Affine Communication Lemma

> Let $X$ be a scheme. $U, \ V$ are open affine subschemes of $X$. Then given $x \in U \cap V \ \ \exists W \subset U \cap V$ such that $x \in W$ is distinguished open in both $U$ and $V$.

So in your case you get two morphisms $$ j_1 : Spec \ \mathcal O_{X,x} \rightarrow U$$ and $$ j_2 : Spec \ \mathcal O_{X,x} \rightarrow V $$

Since $ W$ is a distinguished open affine in $U$ the first morphism factors through $$ Spec \ \mathcal O_{X,x} \rightarrow W \to U$$ and the second factors through $$ Spec \ \mathcal O_{X,x} \rightarrow W \to V$$.

The first arrow in both the factors is the same morphism by commutativity while the second is just inclusion in both cases.
So the composition gives you the same morphism.

Comment: You don't really need distinguished affine if you know $$Mor(X,Y) \simeq Hom_{Rings} (\Gamma (Y,\mathcal O(Y)) , \Gamma (X,\mathcal O(X) ) )$$ if Y is affine.